# WPF Brush with Image texture

Tags: wpf, textures, inkcanvas, imagebrush

Using WPF, I have an InkCanvas which has its background set to an image. I want to draw over this image with a brush that has the texture of another image. I know it's possible to use an ImageBrush and set the source of it to an image, but my understanding is you can only paint an entire shape at once (e.g. fill a rectangle). I want to be able to paint on my InkCanvas and wherever I stroke, have this other image draw on top. How can I do this?